# How to automatically create the primary key that has the following series A001000001 ... A001xxxxxx in SQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I want to create a `primary key(auto-increment)` which is start with `A001000001`.
Here `A001` would be constant and `000001` would be iterate.

I want rows like this:

[image]

How can I do it using SQL query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For **SQL Server** (you didn't clearly specify which RDBMS you're using), my suggestion would be:

- add a `INT IDENTITY` column to your table - and quite frankly, I would make that column the primary key
- add a computed column to your table that does this "prefixing"

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  EmpID AS 'A001' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)), 7) PERSISTED
)
```

That way, if you insert a row, the `ID` gets set automatically, and the `EmpID` will also be set automatically to values like `A0010000001`, `A0010000002`, .... and so forth.

If you want to put the primary key on the `EmpID` column, then you need to make sure to include the `NOT NULL` specification when creating it:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  EmpID AS 'A001' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)), 7) PERSISTED NOT NULL
)
```

and then you can put the primary key constraint on that column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmpID)
```

Comment: Hey marc_s, Thank a lot for reply. I am using mysql Database server.

Is it work for mysql becuase I am getting some error in mysql? :(

Comment: @vin You'd have to post what error you're getting if you want help resolving that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create BEFORE INSERT trigger, check MAX `id` value, increment it, add prefix, and then insert.

Answer (score -3):

its much easier than you think ;)

CREATE TABLE bob (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     foo CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;