# employee id automatic generate with prefix

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, triggers

i am so confuse i want employee id  is automatic  generate with prefix format
i know that is possible from before trigger in sql server
i am follow the post 
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/set-custom-auto-generatedincrement.html

```
USE [test1]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Users]    Script Date: 03/08/2013 12:28:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [UserId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

And the display is

```
    UserId  UserName    LastName    Location
08U13000    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13001    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13002    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13003    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13004    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13005    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13006    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13007    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13008    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13009    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13010    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13011    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13012    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13013    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13014    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
08U13015    SureshDasari    Dasari  Chennai
```

[How to automatically create the primary key that has the following series A001000001 ... A001xxxxxx in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152960/how-to-automatically-create-the-primary-key-that-has-the-following-series-a00100)

but i want to do it from insert before trigger 
and this trigger work in same table and same row 
ex -

```
INSERT INTO Users (UserName,LastName,Location) VALUES('SureshDasari','Dasari','Chennai')
```

and userid automatic created ? like --08U13015,08U13014

i was doing it from insert into inserted table but error can not insert in inserted or deleted table
or any other method 
please help me 
thanks in advance

Comment: The answer in the question you linked to has the solution for you. Why can't you use that? An identity column that is used in a computed persisted primary key column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by [@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153031/569436) in the question is the way to do it.

In your case it would look like this:

```
create table Users
(
  Id int identity (3000, 1),
  UserId as '08U1'+right('0000'+cast(Id as varchar(5)), 5) persisted,
  UserName varchar(50),
  LastName varchar(50),
  Location varchar(50),
  constraint PK_Users primary key (UserId)
)
```

I would not do it like suggested [here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/set-custom-auto-generatedincrement.html). You will have duplicates if you ever delete a row or in case of concurrency.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a911c/1)