# PHP SQL: Automatically generate ID / auto-increment with Prefix in a registration

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I've coded a registration system which where I wanted to have an ID with a Prefix on it. Been debugging for a couple hours on this already and decided to create a post here already. Tried looking for threads about this issue but they were mostly for SQL SERVER.

Was looking onto [@Mikael Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289098) query, and turn it to work on my side but I failed.

My Example:

```
CREATE TABLE 2njaho1fluahymj1auusz5ormx5zmraqqpdrmsut0eotpjzk2(
 wuZ7gIfEz9UAZydySMnE5e1h28Nqvd4Kmk46Ovko1CiDvsf0iDRDC INT IDENTITY(10000,1),
 5nJDfmCpaYwEvIbzShL35uhnbcI4kKmUicxCDaHHRQlc49VUoPh4a AS '#QWE-'+right('00000'+cast(wuZ7gIfEz9UAZydySMnE5e1h28Nqvd4Kmk46Ovko1CiDvsf0iDRDC AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
 G5cWsbp6ob2DKgZVwZnzguSpdZacwXXfHvl7Bo4rLB5BT4uI5lNAK VARCHAR(300),
 T8x4q5RfqVyK5Eoae9UmVEIMF7FwzK00e0vzpYHB5NMr6mDO VARCHAR(300),
 0SUdlsy5q0b9rwD2ePJHLuCeWn8q8vyFquB0hf0f3v0VC43m VARCHAR(300),
 Guwox6dyV7faJZlWxCyKIeStrO9t7xDbKIIXMGx6bb3QucYAI8mMC VARCHAR(300),
 X3nIkFzS6KyaksZz9iBCyOUKaq96lK15bTIuDsou8e3cfI49VVsTS VARCHAR(300),
 82HQunAIr3kEEeCn3JypweDhRMDxAljIMufT3NZB5W4aB3Ns2qSPi VARCHAR(300),
 3HTMIH1dzv6roy4SXmUozupWzOGrzCKwQ7K3qZIFeyNQahIkIGRIe VARCHAR(300),
 FP6U0wzvs06kXt6gQb7SXeathDXZUCAayQbBaMbSItdn9py6JO61i VARCHAR(300),
 L4u7NxC0t8Gvv2BzWbcR3eFmDTVgCmrZfquzgd2YvBRUAa2RCFv6y VARCHAR(300),
 Lx4WTEWUPCtwi6f5TMtxhuyIEfYcOxIziGjBM2c5IdEmM0jrehYcW VARCHAR(300),
 lQg6bMRmFbwx5yP7gRgmhONOvqTOXMLy08PLeBSdBGug8Ujz6HX6u VARCHAR(300),
 PRIMARY KEY(5nJDfmCpaYwEvIbzShL35uhnbcI4kKmUicxCDaHHRQlc49VUoPh4a)
);
```

The actual error I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AS
>   '#JWT-'+right('00000'+cast(wuZ7gIfEz9UAZydySMnE5e1h28Nqvd4Kmk46Ovko1CiDvsf0iD'
>   at line 3

Which is I guess it's because of it not being compatible to RDBMS I'm using.

Comment: What kind of names did you give to the fields???

Comment: @BogdanDoicin Haha, I just thought it's cool to name the columns encrypted, and I know I'm only making it difficult to myself but it's alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Generated" columns were introduced in [*MariaDB 10.2*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/)

Also read about `ZEROFILL`:

```
id INT(6) ZEROFILL
```

will give you 6-digit numbers displayed with leading zeros.  No need for the `RIGHT`, etc.

Anyway `CONCAT( , )` is used for concatenation, not `+`.